# How to save the img tag image to Folder via save as dialog box

Tags: javascript, html

How to make the Save as Dialog box in html design help with Javascript.

I have one img tag and I would like to save the image to local drive via button click.

Thanks

Comment: check thi [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7952401/3168859)

Comment: I would like to open the dialog box to choose the folder to save the img. But above the link is download the img.

Comment: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3EjUg/85/) of mine..is this what you want???

Comment: NO. I want to save that cat image to my local folder. e.g: d:/my image/ that cat image.

Comment: Put the save button and if we click the save button, save as dialog box should open to select the local drive and save the image.

Comment: you can select the local drive from the popup right...in my fiddle..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a browser setting, not something that can be controller by the web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3EjUg/85/)

You can use

```
<a href="your_image.jpg" download="/path/to/image">  Download This Image</a>
```

eg:

```
<a href="myimage.jpg" download="images/gallery/1.jpg">Download This Image</a>
```

Comment: This attribute is not supported in IE. You can see if the support is enough for your case: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: in that case i think its difficult to do just with javascript..we should try a server-side  scripting language like php..

Comment: @Lal Really appreciate your help. I am using the Chrome. I would like to save the image to local drive by choosing the folder form the dialog box. you just right click on the image and choose save as image. one dialog box will show right. thats what am expecting when click the button.

Comment: please check this-http://prntscr.com/5o1t7i

Comment: isnt that the same dialog box that pops up..check my fiddle once more..

Comment: Hey @Maninblack ...did you get it???

Comment: @Lal I think your dialog pops out only if you don't have the default download directory in your browser.. Because I can't see it as well

Comment: OMG its working well for me..in chrome..in which are you testing @m_pro_m ???

Comment: But from my side, the image download when click the download button.

Comment: You too testing in chrome???i think these are broeser settings..in firefox it just downloads to the default downloads folder..i dont think that can be changed

Comment: am testing in chrome.

Comment: See this [link](https://github.com/kaepora/miniLock/issues/174)..it addresses that issue..

Comment: i just disable the default download in chrome and firefox. not it is asked to save to location :),