# url in canvas2image function to save image to particular location

Tags: javascript, image, download, html2canvas

I am creating a chart in partial `div` on pageload. I am converting that into an image using html2canvas lib. That image should get saved to the application's directory.

Using canvas2image lib I want to download and save that image to disk. How should I pass the url?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951326/save-image-to-users-disk-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas library supplies a canvas as an argument to the `onrendered` function. You can use `toDataURL` of the canvas to get the image data in base64 format.

```
html2canvas($parentNode, {
                                    width: 300,
                                    height:300,
                                    onrendered: function(canvas) {                                        
                                        var myData = canvas.toDataURL(); 
                                    }               
                           });
```

Now link this data with an anchor element to make it downloadable as done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file) question.

Comment: OP is using [canvas2image](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image) library which takes a canvas element as input. What he wants is not implemented in this library, which almost just does what you are doing btw...

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for the reply. but the thing is I am not using any link to download it, it should get downloaded and saved internally on page load, as I am using that image in PDF download latter. I used the above solution earlier. but that is not the way it should get performed.

Comment: There is no way you can save an image to disk without telling the user. The closest you can get is to have a popup asking where he would like to save it. If you need the image on your site later on, I think you should post it to the server, store it and load it from there later.

Comment: There is no user activity involved in this functionality. I think you are right. I will do it from server side only. Thanks Jonas Grumann

Comment: OR you can save it to the LocalStorage or SessionStorage instead of the server. But this is only few MBs wide.