# Convert response to new Image

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to convert a HTTP Get response into Image() object?

currently i use:

```
backImage = new Image()
backImage.src = "http://www.example.com/someimage.jpg";
```

i want to use my web api (which serves HttpResponseMessage):

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(Guid id)
        {
           // my logic and image extraction
           var file = new FileInfo("path-to-my-image");
           var fileStream = file.OpenRead();
           var response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StreamContent(fileStream) };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = file.Length;
                return response;
            }
```

which i currently invoke via

```
this.http.get("http://www.example.com/api/GetImage/"+id);
```

When i test it in Postman i returns the response and renders the image.

I am trying to find out if its possible to convert that response and store it in the Image() object as per example.

Comment: What are you returning in `GetImage` API?

Comment: HttpResponseMessage containing the image

Comment: does your method read the `.jpg` file and sent the stream as the respose to the client?

Comment: yea it does, just updated the question showing response

Comment: i guess you dont need `http.get`. Just directly set the URL to the `img.src` like `img.src = "http://www.example.com/api/GetImage/my-id.jpg"` as you are setting all the reqired header values that tell the client that incoming respose is a file of jpg type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return base64 value of your image:

```
var returnString = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
```

example on client side:

```
this.http
 .get("http://www.example.com/api/GetImage/"+id)
 .then(x=>{
    backImage = new Image()
    backImage.src = x;
   //render
});
```

example of controller:

```
public object GetImage(Guid id)
{
  string base64String;

  Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("path to filename"+id);
  base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

  return "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
}
```

Comment: i've expanded your answer to help others with complete picture (controller + client side)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [setgetgo](http://www.setgetgo.com/randomimage/) API that returns image based on ID

```
var img = new Image();
var generateImageId = () => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100000);
img.src = "http://setgetgo.com/randomimage/get.php?key=" + generateImageId();
document.body.appendChild(img)
```

**Working fiddler [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bqk7mrh9/1/)**

---

To save the image to disk checkout this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37521282/1848109)